# He doesn't like chatting on the Internet

Tags: перевод, выражения

In Russian, we use **нравиться** to express likes.

> Я им нравлюсь.
>   They like me.

Google translate, however, gave me this for the translation of

> He doesn't like chatting on the Internet.
>   ему не нравится **в** чате в Интернете.

Why not

> Чат в интернете ему не нравится

Or

> Ему не нравится чат в интернете.

Comment: I wouldn't consider Google Translate the highest authority if I were you.

Comment: It certainly isn't. However, I've got nothing better to use. Have you got any suggestions ?

Comment: https://translate.yandex.ru/  He doesn't like chatting on the Internet. -> Он не любит общаться в Интернете.  Яндекс often(not always) better then google for rus<->eng translate

Comment: @PerfectGundam: ... or you can use a site like Lang-8, where you can write anything and get feedback, corrections, suggestions, variants from thousands of native speakers.

Comment: http://www.translate.ru/ He doesn't like chatting on the Internet. -> Ему не нравится болтать в Интернете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
He doesn't like chatting on the Internet.
Ему не нравится в чате в Интернете.
Чат в интернете ему не нравится
Ему не нравится чат в интернете.
```

1. He doesn't like **chatting** on the Internet.

   Он не любит **чатиться** в интернете.

   Ему не нравится **чатиться** в интернете. (when "чатиться" used, "в интернете" is redundant)

   verb, process

   чатиться = "to chat", Russified, wide used

   общаться, болтать в интернете = any communication. including any multimedia
2. Чат в интернете ему не нравится / Ему не нравится **чат** в Интернете.

   He doesn't like **a chat** on the Internet.

   noun, place
3. Чат в интернете = a chat (each or any), not "the chat"

   Тот(этот) чат в интернете = the chat

   %имя_чата% ему не нравится = he doesn't like %chat_name%

   "В кроватке" ему не нравится = he doesn't like In-The-Bed-Chat
4. some Russified words :))

   — чатиться = to chat

   — скайпиться = to skype

   — сёрфить (редко используется) = "сидеть в интернете" (часто используется) = to surf

   — смситься, эсемеситься, эсэмэситься = to SMS

   — аська, васька = icq. Here is a wordplay. Ася — это женское имя, Аська — уменьшительно-ласкательное Ася. "Я **в аське**" means "I'm **in the ICQ**", "I'm **online in the ICQ**". Васька = Вася = Василий — мужское имя.

Comment: One more quetion, even though you don't chat or skype with yourself, скайпить**ся** is valid and the correct form ?

Comment: @PerfectGundam А что Вас смущает? Возвратная форма? Возвратные глаголы в русском языке могут употребляться в различных случаях. Непосредственно здесь имеет место так называемое "взаимно-возвратное действие".

Comment: @PerfectGundam Moreover you can only 'чатиться', there's no such word 'чатить' or 'скайпить'.

Comment: @PerfectGundam it's not the reflexiveness of the verb, the `скайпиться` by itself might sound lame or overly-slangish. While `чатиться` is a part of an internet person's everyday vocab, `скайпиться` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

This time Google was wrong. All your suggestions are correct. Feel free to use them.